# How to address class instances by index

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

How would I go about addressing class instances by index? For example if I have

```
class Body(object):
    def __init__(self, attribute1, attribute2)
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2

class1 = Body(1,2)
class2 = Body(3,4)
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
Body[1].attribute1
```

and it would return the value 1.

Comment: Make a dict. Store your objects in a dict.

Comment: What's the `1` supposed to be? Is it the `attribute1` value, or the number you put in the variable name? If it's supposed to be the number in the variable name, use a list instead of numbered variables. (If it's the `attribute1` value, a dict would be appropriate.)

Comment: this sounds like a really terrible idea ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always put the instances in a list:

```
classes = [Body(1,2), Body(3,4)]
```

Then you can index the list:

```
>>> classes[0].attribute1   # attribute1 of the first element in the list
1

>>> classes[1].attribute2   # attribute2 of the second element in the list
4
```

Note that indices start with `0` not `1`.

---

By the way you're missing a `:` after `def __init__(self, attribute1, attribute2)`.

---

If you literally want your behavior you can use a metaclass to do that (not recommended!):

```
class IndexableClass(type):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        """Called when the class (not instances!) is created."""
        self._instances = []   # a class attribute keeping references to the instances

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Called when the class is indexed."""
        return self._instances[index]

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Called when a new instance is created."""
        res = type.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._instances.append(res)
        return res

class Body(object, metaclass=IndexableClass):
    def __init__(self, attribute1, attribute2):
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2

class1 = Body(1,2)
class2 = Body(3,4)

Body[0].attribute1   # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to put them in a collection of some sort, like a list or tuple.

```
class Body(object):
    def __init__(self, attribute1, attribute2)
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2


class1 = Body(1,2)
class2 = Body(3,4)
bodies = [class1, class2]
bodies[1].attribute1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of class instances:

```
classes = [class1, class2]
print(classes[1].attribute1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Body(object):
    bodies = []
    def __init__(self, attribute1, attribute2)
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2
        Body.bodies.append(self)

class1 = Body(1,2)
class2 = Body(3,4)
Body.bodies[0]
Body.bodies[1]
```

`Bodies` is static list. Every time new body obiect is created it automatically adds itself to the list.

Comment: This may be a slightly high-level for OP, but if we don't want want to keep the instances around just because they are in the list we should append a weakref to the list: `Body.bodies.append(weakref.ref(self, Body.bodies.remove))`